# How to use Vagrant provisioning to install a package without download?

Tags: linux, yum, virtual-machine, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant boxes for several purposes, and in most cases the prepared boxes I can download are totally sufficient.  However, sometimes I need one or a few additional packages installed on the box—for regular activities, not one-time use.

For example, I have a Vagrant box on my Mac (Linux guest on Mac host) which I primarily want for easy access to built-in Linux documentation (`man` pages, `info` pages, etc.)  However, the box I am using doesn't have the `man` package installed when I first `vagrant up`.

If I just install the package manually, it will only last until the next `vagrant destroy`.  If I use `vagrant halt` instead, I'll build up cruft on my system, which defeats the purpose of using `vagrant` as opposed to simply a Virtual Box.

I know the *general* answer to this is vagrant provisioning, and it could be as simple as a script with a single command `sudo yum install man`.  (Although actually I don't even know specifically how to do that.)  However, rather than downloading the man package and all dependencies each time I start the vagrant box, I would rather download those packages *once*, store them on my host system, and load them into the vm each time I `vagrant up`.

I have already run `sudo yum install man --downloadonly` on the guest, to get the packages I need, and `sudo cp -r /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/base/packages/ /vagrant/` to put the package files on my host.

So my question is really twofold:

1. What is the vagrant provisioning syntax to use for: (a) calling a script (to be stored in the same directory as the Vagrantfile), or (b) if possible, embedding a single command in the Vagrantfile (such as `sudo yum install man`)?
2. How can I give `yum` the option flags needed to install a package from a local directory (`/vagrant`) *and* to install any needed dependencies from that same local directory rather than from an online repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just encountered this use case again; I will make a succinct record here of how I handled it.

I wanted to download (but not install) Git and PostgreSQL, and then install them during the vagrant provision process.

I used the following command from a fresh VM to download the packages with all dependencies (after `sudo mkdir /vagrant/packages`):

```
sudo yumdownloader --destdir=/vagrant/packages/ --resolve -y git postgresql
```

The trick with this command is, it downloads way too much.  The next step was to establish the RPMs that I *actually* needed for the install.  I did this by attempting:

```
sudo yum install /vagrant/packages/git-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.x86_64.rpm /vagrant/packages/postgresql-8.4.20-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

And pressing "No" at the confirmation prompt because I could see it was planning to download dependencies.  I took the listed dependencies and added them to my command:

```
sudo yum install /vagrant/packages/git-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.x86_64.rpm /vagrant/packages/postgresql-8.4.20-6.el6.x86_64.rpm /vagrant/packages/perl-* /vagrant/packages/postgresql-libs-8.4.20-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

This would successfully work without downloading anything, so I then ran:

```
cd /vagrant/packages/
mkdir save
mv /vagrant/packages/git-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.x86_64.rpm /vagrant/packages/postgresql-8.4.20-6.el6.x86_64.rpm /vagrant/packages/perl-* /vagrant/packages/postgresql-libs-8.4.20-6.el6.x86_64.rpm save/
rm *.rpm
mv save/* .
rmdir save
```

Result: A "packages" directory with *only* the dependencies actually needed from the fresh Vagrant image.

Then by adding the shell provisioning command to my `Vagrantfile`:

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    yum install -C -y /vagrant/packages/*
  SHELL
```

...I have Git and PostgreSQL installed and ready to use after any `vagrant up`, even if `vagrant destroy` was run.

Answer (score 3):

> For example, I have a Vagrant box on my Mac (Linux guest on Mac host)

It would be interesting to know which distribution this is... Given that you're trying to use `yum` I imagine this is some RH/CentOS/.. stuff?

> which I primarily want for easy access to built-in Linux documentation (man pages, info pages, etc.) However, the box I am using doesn't have the man package installed when I first vagrant up.

I don't know any distribution that doesn't install `man`by default.

If I were you, I'd use one of the official boxes on ATLAS, Debian comes to mind: https://vagrantcloud.com/debian/

### Reply to Q1

Add this to your vagrantfile:

```
$script = <<SCRIPT
echo I am provisioning...
date > /etc/vagrant_provisioned_at
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
end
```

Example taken from
http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html#inline-scripts

This would execute the script at the top, resulting in the creation of `/etc/vagrant_provisioned_at`

Further adapted to your question:

```
$script = <<SCRIPT
yum install man
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
end
```

The provisioning script is run as UID0, so no need for `sudo`.

#### Reply to Q2

I'm a Debian user and as such RedHat illiterate ;-)

IMHO this would be `rpm -hiv <filename>`(`i` =install, `h` = hashmarks, `v` = verbose).

[Related manpage](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html)

Comment: Perfect!  Yes, I'm using CentOS; the vm box is "bento/centos-6.7" and it doesn't come with man.  (Which is an odd setup; my physical CentOS install does.)  `rpm` isn't smart enough to handle dependencies and just exits with an error if given the single file, BUT it *is* smart enough to put a list of filename arguments in dependency sequence.  Since I already downloaded the dependencies as described in my question, I just used `rpm -i /vagrant/packages/*` and it puts them in order and installs them all!  (No need for -hv as it's just run during provisioning.)

Comment: I found the puppetlabs base boxes quite "vanilla", try one of those: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puppetlabs  They have a good naming scheme btw...

Comment: Aha!  Even better; I've just switched over.  Thanks!  Still great to have the provisioning data/know-how; I will use that for my *own* setup and package installs in the future (rather than stuff like `man` which should already be there....)